# How to create an initrd.img file for liveCD for a specific kernel version

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, boot, initrd, live-cd

I've created a LiveCD image (.iso) of CentOS 7.2 and it works fine with the initrd.img file that I took from the http://vault.centos.org/7.2.1511/os/x86_64/images/pxeboot/

its boot up with a kernel version 3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64

However, for my needs, I had to compile a different kernel - 4.14.196
The problem is when I boot to the LiveCD it remained on the older kernel and does not expose me to the modules that exist in the newer kernel.

I tried to create a new initrd.img file with this command:

```
dracut -M --xz initrd.img $(uname -r)
```

But the boot process got stuck  with error:

```
dracut: FATAL: Don't know how to handle 'roor=live:CDLABEL=livecd'
```

My question is how to make proper initrd.img file for a specific kernel version?

Thanks

Comment: The `root=` option is misspelt.

Comment: Is CONFIG_XZ_DEC=y?